# Lost messages with aSmack

Tags: android, smack, asmack

i'm using aSmack in my Android app to receive messages from my Desktop-Jabber-client. This works fine and even if my android phone is offline (after the connection was closed properly) it will receive the offline messages after the next login.

But when i enter the airplane-mode on the phone or shutdown the phone so that the connection is abruptly closed (without calling `disconnect()` on the `Connection`-object) the phone stays "online" in the contact-list of my Desktop-Jabber-client for a while and i can send messages to it. However these messages never arrive. Even though the phone logs in to the server again. These messages are lost.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Losing messages in a chat is not an option. :)

EDIT: Added Test-Code
BroadcastReceiver: http://pastebin.com/cFLzGXgy
Service: http://pastebin.com/wLpQCQfT

The first one is a BroadcastReceiver starting the service (second URL) each time the phone is connected to a network.

PS: This is only a test-code! You must change the server/username/password if you want to use/test it.

Comment: Did you explicitly program the client to do a XEP-13 offline message retrieval on login? The Server should detect that the client has gone offline and if the server supports it, cache the messages for later (xep-13 conform) retrieval.

Comment: The XEP-13-abstract says: "The protocol enables a connecting client to retrieve its offline messages on login in a controlled fashion, without receiving a flood of messages.". So i thought when not using XEP-13 i will still get the offline messages (but not in a controlled fashion). And of course i get "normal" offline messages. Messages are only lost if the connection was closed unexpectedly and the server recognizes this too late. Or am i wrong? I know you're using your own aSmack-fork :) Don't you have these problems?

Comment: IMO there is no such thing that the server recognizes the closed connection "too late" when you are using XMPP over TCP. If the TCP socket is closed before a outstanding message could be send, the server *should* cache the message for later retrieval.
I have never noticed such problems with asmack and openfire on the other side.

Comment: I added my code to the posting above. Just run it on your phone and it will connect to the xmpp-server and reconnect if you change your network (eg. 3g > wlan). Now enable the airplane mode on the phone. You will notice that the phone is still shown as online in your contact-list. Send a msg to the phone. Now disable airplane mode. The service will automatically reconnect to the xmpp-server but you will never see the message, which was sent while being in airplane mode, on the phone. BTW: I can reproduce this behaviour with Beem, which uses asmack too. So what is my mistake in your opinion? :)

Comment: I take (nearly) everything back what I have said :) I could reproduce this with openfire. So IMHO it's a issue on the server side and there is nothing you can do within your client or (a)smack. It looks like openfire currently discards all messages that where send to a client which has a referenced sessions with an IOException, instead of queuing the message as offline message. See also this post http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/45028?tstart=0

Comment: OK, it seems that we have to wait until [XEP-0198](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html) is supported by the jabber-servers and by Smack, see [here](http://op-co.de/blog/posts/XEP-0198/). In Smack it's an [open ticket](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-446) and ejabberd is working on [it's on specification](https://support.process-one.net/browse/EJAB-532). It seems that jabberd and Prosody already support XEP-0198, but i cannot find any (Android-)library ... too bad!

Comment: Uh, well XEP-0198 is the golden cow when it comes to mobile XMPP communication. But it's not that easy to implement, on both sides server and client. Gajim, a python based XMPP client, is currently working on it. I think it will take some time until there is full stream management support on android. Maybe the openfire dev's/community is able to fix this bug [OF-464](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-464) . Which would also help in this case.

Comment: @Biggie I am facing the same problem, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, sry. The project was stopped. Maybe one of the answers below will work. There is a most recent one from December 2014.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to send delivered message from client b to client A when the message arrival. The problem is if the client A is offline (no connection break) the delivered confirm don't send until the user receives the message and the client B can't re-send the message.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to send acknowledgement of receiving the message using Smackx [Message Events](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/messageevents.html)
this will assure the message is delivered else you take corrective action.

Answer (score 1):

this problem occurs when your connection broke.
You need "Stream Management" XEP-198 enabled connections to achieve this messages. refer to this blog : http://op-co.de/blog/posts/XEP-0198/ Basically it allows for stanza acknowledgement and stream resumption, which is exactly what you want to do in case.so you should wait till smack will 4.1 release.